# Strange symbol in Xcode4 navigator

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, svn, ide

I would know what this symbol should mean ?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have set up your project with a source code manager (Git repository) you can have different symbols in the navigator depending on the state of the file. 
Source code manager status is shown as a badge in the project navigator, as follows:

M = Locally modified

U = Updated in repository

A = Locally added

D = Locally deleted

I = Ignored

R = Replaced in the repository

[image]